# I am trying to notify the app when someone starts calling using Agora. I have gotten the basic fundamentals of callkit working I am using firebase too

Tags: swift, firebase, callkit, agora.io, pushkit

I don't know how to do this when the app is closed. How do I tell the app that this specific user is calling even when the app is killed and not open.

Comment: I think you may be looking for https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [PushKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit)'s VoIP notifications in order to be able to receive calls using CallKit. Unfortunately, Firebase doesn't support VoIP pushes.